# Using the MIN function in the having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, min, having

I want to get the name of the employee who has the minimum salary. Is there a way to do this using only one query? I have given my query below, it doesn't work because the having clause requires a condition. Is there any way to give a condition in the having clause that will retreive the employee name with the minimum salary?

```
SELECT first_name,min(salary) as "sal"
FROM Employees
GROUP BY first_name 
having min(salary);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using `ROWNUM`?

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT first_name, salary
     FROM Employees
     ORDER BY salary
) WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Thanks alot. But I was trying to do it in one query

Comment: Sindu_, how many queries can you see? This is just one query.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I'm trying to do this without using a sub query

Comment: What problem do you have with subqueries? They're one of the most powerful features of SQL.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I don't have a problem with it. I just wanted to know if its possible to do it without using a subquery

Comment: The answer to that question will depend on what version of Oracle you're using. Oracle 12c supports TOP-N queries: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php

Comment: simplified the subquery

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT first_name, salary  as "sal" 
FROM   employees
WHERE  salary =(SELECT MIN(salary) 
                FROM   employees);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I was trying to find a way to do it in a single query.

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution, inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/2905135):

```
SELECT e1.first_name, e1.salary AS "sal"
FROM Employees e1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees e2
ON (e1.id <> e2.id AND e1.salary > e2.salary)
WHERE e2.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

With a single `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT MIN( first_name ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary ASC, first_name ASC ) AS first_name,
       MIN( salary     ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY salary ASC, first_name ASC ) AS salary
FROM   Employees;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b995/4/0)

However, if there are multiple people with the same minimum salary then this will only get the one with the name which is first alphabetically.

You can get all the names, but it does require multiple `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT first_name, salary
FROM   Employees
WHERE  salary = ( SELECT MIN(salary) FROM Employees );
```

But having multiple `SELECT` statements isn't a bad thing.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b995/4/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

Comment: This is incorrect; the OP is using Oracle and TOP is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the employee with the lowest salary why don't you use **Order By** ..

```
SELECT top 1 first_name,min(salary) as LowestSalary
FROM Employees order by Salary asc
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried your query in SQL developer. It gives this error: 
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: This is incorrect; the OP is using Oracle and TOP is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation:

```
SELECT first_name,min(salary) as "sal"
FROM Employees
GROUP BY first_name 
having min(salary) >0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with only one query, while also retrieving all employees with the minimum salary (example: you have a minimum salary of $40,000, but two employees have this exact salary) you could join the table with itself. This solution also uses the 'having' clause that you included in your original question.

```sql
SELECT e.first_name,e.salary AS "sal"
FROM Employees e, Employees e2
GROUP BY first_name 
HAVING MIN(e2.salary)=e.salary;
```