# Oracle: select values only from row with min(id)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
   ass.assessmentAmount -- want to fetch assessmentAmount of min(ass.assessmentId)
   ass.assessmentId
FROM
   --bunch of joins  
WHERE
ass.assessmentId = (SELECT min(ass2.assessmentId) FROM Assessment ass2
   --same bunch of joins
```

It looks very confusing because I have 6 joins with conditions and I don't want to repeat it two times. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the MIN function in the having clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761714/using-the-min-function-in-the-having-clause)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `MIN( ass.assessmentId ) OVER ()` analytic function:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ass.assessmentAmount,
         ass.assessmentId,
         MIN( ass.assessmentId ) OVER () AS min_assessmentId
  FROM   --bunch of joins
)
WHERE assessmentId = min_assessmentId;
```

You can also use `RANK()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ass.assessmentAmount,
         ass.assessmentId,
         RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY ass.assessmentId ) AS rnk
  FROM   --bunch of joins
)
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

If `assessmentId` is `UNIQUE` and can only have a single row as a minimum then you could replace `RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`; however, you could also then get the desired result using the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ass.assessmentAmount,
         ass.assessmentId
  FROM   --bunch of joins
  ORDER BY ass.assessmentId ASC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a CTE with a row_number

```
with CTE as
(
select assessmentId, 
       assessmentAmount , 
       row_number() over (order by assessmentid asc) as rn
from --bunch of joins
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Using `ROW_NUMBER` will only give the same answer as the OP's query if the `assessmentId` column is `UNIQUE`. If multiple rows can have the same minimum `assessmentId` then this will not give the same answer.