# How to do order by min() of some column?

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I am pretty new to SQL. I want a query which should do order by on min of some column. Below is the query i want.

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( 
         SELECT p.PROJECT_ID,
                p.PROJECT_NAME,
                p.PROJECT_TYPE
         FROM   PROJECT p
                LEFT OUTER JOIN code c
                ON p.PROJECT_ID= c.PROJECT_ID
         WHERE  p.PROJECT_NAME IN ('test')
         ORDER BY min(c.LABEL) ASC
       )
WHERE  rownum <= 25;
```

Why i need it this way is. I have one table PROJECT.

```
PROJECT_ID  PROJECT_NAME    PROJECT_TYPE
1           a               test1
2           b               test2
```

i have another table code which has project_id as foreign key.

```
ID  PROJECT_ID  LABEL
1      1         a
2      1         b
3      1         c
4      2         d
```

now when i will join it on project_id and make order by on code.label it will give me 4 records three with project id 1 and 1 with project id 2. But my requirement is to sort the project based on the codes label. so logically i want two records . One for project id 1 with min vale of label of all the possible combinations of project id 1 i.e with label a and other with project id 2. So that's why i want to sort it based on min of code label. I cannot use group by as it will degrade the performance.

Comment: to use MIN (it is an aggregate function), you have to use the GROUP BY clause to, to group your records.

Comment: where is your "rownum" column coming from?

Comment: I think you just want `ORDER BY c.LABEL`?

Comment: You should show some sample data & desired output. As it is, as Glenn says, just ordering by c.LABEL _seems_ like it's what you need.

Comment: I cannot use just order by as doing that gives me duplicate results because of join.

Comment: Try This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761714/using-the-min-function-in-the-having-clause

Comment: Without a GROUP BY clause you have only one row group (all rows in your join) and one value of min(c.LABEL): sorting by a constant key doesn't make sense.

Comment: You don't select any column from c. At least c.ID and c.LABEL are important and selecting them would make the results more comprehensible.

Comment: An example of desired output will be helpful.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please explain in words what data you have and what you want to get out of it.

Comment: I have updated the questions with required details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use a MIN(  )
you need  a group by  eg:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  ( 
      SELECT p.PROJECT_ID,
              p.PROJECT_NAME,
              p.PROJECT_TYPE
      FROM PROJECT p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN code c
      ON p.codeId=c.ID
      WHERE p.PROJECT_NAME IN ('test')
      GROUP BY .PROJECT_ID,
              p.PROJECT_NAME,
              p.PROJECT_TYPE
      ORDER BY min(c.LABEL) ASC
      )
     WHERE rownum <= 25;
```

and in some db you must select the column you need  for order by  eg:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  ( 
      SELECT p.PROJECT_ID,
              p.PROJECT_NAME,
              p.PROJECT_TYPE,
               min(c.LABEL)
      FROM PROJECT p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN code c
      ON p.codeId=c.ID
      WHERE p.PROJECT_NAME IN ('test')
      GROUP BY .PROJECT_ID,
              p.PROJECT_NAME,
              p.PROJECT_TYPE
      ORDER BY min(c.LABEL) ASC
      )
     WHERE rownum <= 25;
```